# Is speech to text functionality and voice analysis possible in ios 8 and above

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios9

I need to integrate this functionality on the application I am currently working on.

Though I came to know about OpenEars but do we have support for iOS 8 and 9.

Please do suggest any other latest and reliable apis for voice recording and analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) support the new iOS8 and iOS9. OpenEars just need AudioToolbox and AVFoundation framework to be added.

There are other API's

Free/OpenSource:

http://www.ispeech.org/

http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php

Paid:

http://www.creaceed.com/ceedvocal/about

Comment: Ok @iPrabu, will try it out. Thank you buddy

Answer (score -1):

Speech to text is supported natively with the class **[AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/index.html)**, available since iOS7. AVSpeechSynthesizer is a "free" TTS system integrated iOS: unless you really need specialized voices, e.g. child voices, this is your best option for speech synthesis.

The only "non online" speech recognition SDKs which I am aware of is **[CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download)** written in C and which supports very few speaker languages. You will probably need to adapt it yourself for iOS.

There are several other APIs, available as paid services. Your mileage with API based assistive speech services will vary.

Comment: Any tutorial to implement STT, not TTS ?

Comment: AVSpeechSynthesizer is just for Text to Speech (TTS) not for STT.

Comment: Exact, but that solves FOR FREE a half of your problem.
You might find a 100% solution via a PAID service (it can be free while you are testing the service, but after the initial trial, you will have to pay).
Even if you resort to a paid service for voice recognition (STT), it makes perfect sense non to pay for a service which iOS supplies at zero cost (TTS). If you need a fully local and zero cost solution, you could try integrating CMUSphinx.